# When accessing PHP files, nginx throws an 404 error

Tags: php, nginx, php-cgi

Right, sorry for the previous, recent questions I've asked about nginx, this is just doing my head in.

I've enabled PHP using fastcgi_php and it works just fine, however, when I access to a PHP file, e.g.

> http://domain.com/info.php

(which applies to `var/www/domain.com/www/info.php`)

Which includes the `phpinfo()` and nginx throws an 404 error... if I access to a normal file, e.g.

> http://domain.com/index.html

It seems fine... how come nginx won't process with the PHP files?

This is the `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com`.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  domain.com *.domain.com;

    access_log /var/www/domain.com/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/domain.com/logs/nginx_error.log;

    root   /var/www/domain.com/www/;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Enable PHP
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_php;
}
```

I have no clue what to do further...

EDIT:

My `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_php`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: What does error log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have installed php-cgi `apt-get install php5-cgi`. Next create a startup script for fastCGI PHP.

Create the file `/etc/init.d/fastcgi-php` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
BIND_DIR=/var/run/php-fastcgi
BIND="$BIND_DIR/php.sock"
USER=www-data
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=8
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000

PHP_CGI=/usr/bin/php-cgi
PHP_CGI_NAME=`basename $PHP_CGI`
PHP_CGI_ARGS="- USER=$USER PATH=/usr/bin PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=$PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=$PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS $PHP_CGI -b $BIND"
RETVAL=0

start() {
    echo -n "Starting PHP FastCGI: "
    mkdir $BIND_DIR
    chown -R $USER $BIND_DIR
    start-stop-daemon --quiet --start --background --chuid "$USER" --exec /usr/bin/env -- $PHP_CGI_ARGS
    RETVAL=$?
    echo "$PHP_CGI_NAME."
}
stop() {
    echo -n "Stopping PHP FastCGI: "
    killall -q -w -u $USER $PHP_CGI
    RETVAL=$?
    rm -rf $BIND_DIR
    echo "$PHP_CGI_NAME."
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
  ;;
    stop)
        stop
  ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
  ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: php-fastcgi {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
  ;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

Finally run the following commands (all as root if in Debian, or with `sudo` if in Ubuntu)

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/fastcgi-php
update-rc.d fastcgi-php defaults
/etc/init.d/fastcgi-php start
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Now check if the info.php file shows up correctly.

Otherwise please post the output of the domains error log and access log.

Comment: It works! However, I got **two** errors when doing your steps `update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/fastcgi-php missing LSB information` and - `/etc/init.d/fastcgi-php: line 1: !#/bin/bash: No such file or directory`. Is there anything to worry about?

Comment: One another thing, if access to a PHP file that doesn't exist, I get this output in my browser: `No input file specified.`

Comment: Sorry my fault: The first line should be `#!/bin/bash` instead of `!#/bin/bash` I also corrected it in my answer.

Comment: Regarding the `No input file specified` try adding `error_page  404  /404.html;` above `error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html; in your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com` file and restart nginx.

Comment: I did that, didn't prevent the `No input file specified` error. The file also exists in `/var/www/domain.com/www/404.html`.

Comment: Another try: can you add a new line with `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;` on your `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_php` file right above `fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php.sock;` ? Restart nginx and check again.

Comment: Nice, glad it worked :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1483/discussion-between-youbook-and-george-tasioulis)

Comment: I need a little help with something, if that's not a problem?

Comment: Really? php-cgi? Is his a joke or something? At the very least you should recommend php-fpm

Comment: @MartinF man check his question first... he already HAD php-cgi installed. I just went on with his current configuration.

Comment: Check out your own answer: "First make sure you have installed php-cgi apt-get install php5-cgi. Next create a startup script for fastCGI PHP." This is still one of those "Shoot yourself in the foot" answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have fundamentally misunderstood how PHP works with Nginx. Your assumption that Apache == Nginx is incorrect. Nginx does **not** embed PHP within itself so if you try to access a PHP file then it's PHP throwing the 404 and *not* Nginx.

Sadly you have hidden your PHP configuration with `include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_php;` so I can't actually tell you if you've configured Nginx correctly, so please do provide your full configuration.

Meanwhile, you can verify that PHP is actually throwing the 404 by checking the returned headers and checking if you have `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8`. If this is present then you need to verify that you're sending PHP the proper file path via the SCRIPT_FILENAME fastcgi_param. If that one is correct then PHP cannot read the file due to improper permissions, this can either be read access on the file itself or execute access on any of the parent directories.

Comment: Updated my post, sorry for not including the configuration file.

Comment: Remove the trailing slash from your root directive as `$fastcgi_script_name;` already starts with a /. Other than that the last paragraph with file permissions still apply.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify that part?

Comment: I don't see which trailing slash apart from `\.` one and the file directories.